# Why do some of my app icons show like on my iPad?

Tags: ios

I have several apps, and all use a similar, themed icon with different background colours.  All are produced by the same Photoshop psd.
All the icons show perfectly on iPhone 5, 4 and 4S.
However, 2 of them show like the shot below on my iPad 3. Any suggestions?
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: audience may need at least 2 icons to compare the iPhone app icon with iPad app icon, then only they will understand your problem & help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the default icon(empty icon) for iPad, do you have Icon-72.png and Icon-72@2x.png included in your plist?

see https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1686/_index.html

Comment: Thanks. No, I don't have these, but neither do the apps that show up OK on the iPad. They are all iPhone only apps.

Comment: Icon-72.png and Icon-72@2x.png are Optional but recommended, so adding the icons will fix the issue

Comment: Thanks again. I added 2 files (appicon72x72 and appicon144x144) into the Info list, but problem is the same.  Do I have to add them somewhere else?

Comment: normally the icon names should be Icon-72.png and Icon-72@2x.png in info.plist, and the two png images should also be added to your project.   after that doing a clean and rebuild and then reinstall on your iPad and see if the problem get fixed

Comment: The icon files in all my apps are named with the structure, e.g. 'appname app icon 57x57.png', 'app name app icon 144x144.png' and they all work fine on all platforms. The only exceptions are the 2 I mention which show the default icon on my iPad 3.  I have created the 2 you suggested, called 'app name app icon 72x72.png' (and the equivalent 144x144), added them to the project and Info.  Still no joy - problem the same.

Comment: What I just noticed, is that the 2 offending apps have a CFBundleIcons-ipad entry just below the 'Icon Files' one in Info.plist.  The working apps don't have that.

Comment: I think the significant fact might be that the 2 offending apps are the only ones that were started in Xcode 5. All the others were started in 4.6.

Comment: Issue resolved by using Asset Catalog and adding a new 'App Icon' to it. Then all the icon placeholders appeared and I just populated them.  Strange that the default AppIcon doesn't show them all.  Thanks for your pointers!

Comment: I know, but what confuses me is why the default AppIcon set has only 3 placeholders - iPhone iOS5/6 settings/spotlight, iPhone iOS7 spotlight and iPhone app iOS7. Contrast that with when you add a new AppIcon set in, then there are placeholders for iPad as well as lots of others.  Why is that?  I don't understand why we can't just submit the largest required icon - 144x144 - and let the system rescale for all the other sizes. Life would be so much simpler!